# Set where to find the config file for audit4j

Tags: java, audit4j

I've looked all over the documentation, but was unable to find one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Audit4j [documentation](http://audit4j.org/documentation/#configuration) and [javadoc](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/) there are multiple ways to specify the configuration:

1. It can be injected into the [Context](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/org/audit4j/core/Context.html) directly by calling static methods of the [Context](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/org/audit4j/core/Context.html) class (e.g. at application startup **before** doing any audit!):

   - [Context#initWithConfiguration(Configuration configuration)](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/org/audit4j/core/Context.html#initWithConfiguration-org.audit4j.core.Configuration-) with the appropriate [Configuration](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/org/audit4j/core/Configuration.html)
   - or [Context#initWithConfiguration(String configFilePath)](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/org/audit4j/core/Context.html#initWithConfiguration-java.lang.String-) to specify the configuration as file.
2. Other ways to specify the path to the configuration file **without** manually initializing the [Context](http://audit4j.org/apidocs/core/latest/org/audit4j/core/Context.html) are:

   - Setting path in environment variable "**AUDIT4J_CONF_FILE_PATH**"
   - Setting path in Java system property variable "**audit4j.conf.file.path**"
3. Also the configuration file can be put into the *application classpath* or the *user directory*. In this case the name of the configuration file has to be ***"audit4j.conf.yml"*** or ***"audit4j.conf.yaml"*** for *YAML* style or ***"audit4j.conf.xml"*** for *XML* style.